# How can I change the color text according to it's content in React and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to change the color text according to the text content, but this is not working for me. Any Ideas why?   Thanks a lot.   I'm using React.

```
<p>
    <b>Online, yes/no:</b>
    <span className={ {link.activated}  === 'Online' ? "text-success" : "text-primary"}>{link.activated}</span>
</p>
```

Comment: What si `text`?? Is it located in state, variable, or what??

Comment: It's pretty hard to help without seeing all the code. Where is text being set?

Comment: text it's the same variable showed...  I just edit the code, please take a look. What I want it's when {link.activated} is equal to "Online"  change to green. {link.activated} it's a variable that it's rendering perfectly before trying to change the color dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your stylesheet is already setup, then this should work:

```
<p>
    <b>Online, yes/no:</b>
    <span className={ link.activated  === 'Online' ? "text-success" : "text-primary"}>{link.activated}</span>
</p>
```

You basically do not need to wrap `link.activated` in curly brackets inside `className`

Comment: Works perfect !